# TypeScript - run functions after compiling typescript

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, compilation, console

I am developing a hobby project where I use CefSharp to build a C# application with an Angular TypeScript interface.

At the moment I am using websockets to talk back to the backend, I made my own websocket implementation in C# (which might be part of the problem I'm having). The problem is the fact that sometimes my backend doesn't receive a message from the frontend while it should, which I somewhat fixed by sending a completely random message after the message that has to be sent (I didn't have this issue in Chrome itself, only CefSharp started to have this issue).

Now I was reading upon CefSharp and came across the fact that you can execute JavaScript methods from C#, which would basically solve the need for websockets.

The only issue that I am seeing here, is that I can't run/find functions written in TypeScript after compiling. Is there a way to make pure JavaScript functions that, after compiling TypeScript, are still accessible? And, not unimportant, can those JavaScript functions call TypeScript functions (like functions from other services)?

Another example is: can I execute TypeScript functions from the Chrome console?

Comment: After compilation, it's **all** JS. That's what TS compiles to, that's what `tsc` does.

Comment: I know that, the only issues is, that I have no clue how to access a specific function in the compiled JS. There is not much information to be found, or my google skills are lacking x) .

Answer (score 1):

If your typescript functions are in the global scope, the compiled javascript functions will also be in the global scope, so you can just call them from the console. If you use `import` `export` and modules, your code will be unavailable in the global scope. Websockets seem like a good idea in that case.

typescript

```
class Test{
    doSomething(){
        console.log("hi!")
    }
}
```

compiled to es5 javascript

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype.doSomething = function () {
        console.log("hi!");
    };
    return Test;
}());
```

from the browser console or your c# application

```
let t = new Test();
t.doSomething();
```